# Transformar Array Select2 y luego combinar para insertar Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy utilizando selec2 multiple para obviamente seleccionar una o mas opciones (estáticas)

recibo como respuesta del select2 este array con lo seleccionado:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "service"
  1 => "frenos"
]
```

lo anterior lo quiero convertir a esto:

```
$trabajosSel=array(
  "service" => 1,
  "frenos" => 1,
)
```

necesito convertir ese array para luego combinarlo con el siguiente array que recibo de mis otros campos formulario

```
 $request=array(
                "fecha" =>now(),
                "solicitado" => $this->solicitud->solicitado,
                "vehiculo_id" => $this->solicitud->vehiculo,
                "patente" =>$patente,
                "kms" => $this->solicitud->kms,
                "solicitado" => $this->solicitud->solicitado,
                "zona" => $zona,
                "usr" => $this->solicitud->usr,
                "status" => 0,          
            );
            $insert=array_merge($request,$trabajosSel);           
            RepairSolicitud::insert($insert);
```

cosa que al combinar ambos me quede :

```
$insert=Array(
               "fecha" =>now(),
                "solicitado" => $this->solicitud->solicitado,
                "vehiculo_id" => $this->solicitud->vehiculo,
                "patente" =>$patente,
                "kms" => $this->solicitud->kms,
                "solicitado" => $this->solicitud->solicitado,
                "zona" => $zona,
                "usr" => $this->solicitud->usr,
                "status" => 0, 
                "service" => 1,
                "frenos" => 1,        

)
```

He intentado con un for de ésta manera

```
$trabajosSel=[];
           
            for ($i=0;$i<count($this->trabajos);$i++){  
                $results=array(                   
                    $this->trabajos[$i]=>  1,
                 );
                 $trabajosSel[]=$results;
            }
```

pero obtengo esto y no se como hacerlo

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "service" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "elect" => 1
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo con un [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php), que itera en cada elemento de un array.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
$trabajos = [
    0 => "service",
    1 => "frenos"
];

$trabajosSel=[];

foreach ($trabajos as $trabajo) {
    $trabajosSel[$trabajo] = 1;
}

var_dump($trabajosSel);
```

Esto devuelve:

```
array(2) {
  ["service"]=>
  int(1)
  ["frenos"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!